# Error in PDF conversion led to lower score on test

Tags: exams, online-learning, online-exam

My daughter is a college student. During her test she was required to use their online system to log in and answer the questions, then convert the results to PDF and upload to the professor. She answered all questions correctly and converted data to PDF on their site and uploaded as instructed.   The PDF however had one blank page (an error) that was deducted from her total score. Her answers were correct but due to circumstances beyond her control there was a faulty PDF. What is the best action?

Comment: Immediately inform the professor. Too late now, but she should have checked the pdf before submitting.

Comment: In almost all cases I know of, you have an opportunity of looking at the final PDF displayed on screen when you upload something. Was that the case here? If so, the circumstances were within in her control.

Comment: It's always disappointing when we're reminded that there are institutions that give marks for pdf conversion and the like.